# Ground Fluctuations

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I have done the following circuit today.

[image]

This is the Arduino sketch I use.

```
int led = 13;
void setup() {                
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(100);
}
```

The above sketch does nothing but alternate HIGH and LOW on pin number 13 every 100 milliseconds. In other words, it provides a clean **5Hz** square wave on pin 13. The question is that, eventhough I have a steady logical **HIGH** level in the output, why do I observe a ripple in the logical **LOW** level when measured across the output LED? The transistor I use is a [BC547](http://www.play.com.br/datasheet/BC547.pdf). The following is the signal I see on the oscilloscope.
[image]

Comment: That ripple is oscillating. What is the primary frequency component of it? Looks like it is about 1Hz.

Comment: Looks like 50Hz to me.

Comment: BTW, you are missing a current limiting resistos for a diode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the transistor is off, the positive lead is effectively *floating*, and therefore picks up the 50Hz emissions from the power facilities permeating the building.

Comment: Ok, How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Attach the lead to something that isn't floating, or don't attempt to instrument this circuit this way.

Comment: Solved by grounding the positive lead of the LED through an 18K resistor. :)